# I accidentally connected CPU2 -P8 to ATX 12V is my mainboard going to be fine?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I accidentally connected CPU2 -P8 to what supposed to be connected to CPU1 -P4.

My PC did not boot and that is how I got aware of the issue.

After connecting the right 4 pin connector the system booted without any issues.

Now I'm a bit worried that I might have damaged something because I realized that the -P8 does not have the same keying as the -P4 connector.

I'm talking about these connectors:

[image]

Is there some sort of detection going on that doesn't provide power to -P8 if there isn't a motherboard installed that doesn't even have a 4+4 CPU Power connector?

My mainboard does not have a 4+4 CPU Power connector, only the 4 pin.

Comment: The voltage are in a range such that if all is now working, the motherboard is probably fine.

Comment: Unlikely that there will be later repercussions. If it initially works after the mix-up, and you've tested the drives (which sometimes need a 12 V bus),  it should continue working for its normal lifespan.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I haven't connected any external drives to my setup because I've used the internal M.2 slot of the motherboard. Any idea where the 12 V bus is going to as well? It's obviously hard to find electrical schematics of _any_ motherboard.